# AngularJS templates not loading/rendering

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

So I'm trying to run an Angular app with a Rails API on Chrome.

I'm trying to render very simple views from their respective controllers.

My users.js controller:

```
'use strict';

var rantlyApp = angular.module('rantlyApp', ['ngRoute']);

rantlyApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/users', {
      templateUrl: '/views/users.html',
      controller: 'UsersCtrl'
    });
}])
.controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users/').success(function(data) {
    $scope.users = data.users;
  });

  $scope.foos = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
}]);
```

users.html view:

```
<div ng-controller='UsersCtrl'>
  <h1>Users</h1>

  <ul ng-repeat="user in users">
    <li>{{user.first_name}}</li>
  </ul>

  <ul ng-repeat="foo in foos">
    <li>{{foo}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The users page renders fine, and I get all the data I want.  But when I try to load my main page, I get nothing.  No errors, just a blank screen (though the navbar and everything else I have in my index.html loads properly).

My main.js controller:

```
'use strict';

var rantlyApp = angular.module('rantlyApp', ['ngRoute']);

rantlyApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });
}])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.awesomeThings = [
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'baz'
  ];

  $scope.addThing = function() {
    $scope.awesomeThings.push($scope.newThing);
    $scope.newThing = '';
  };

}]);
```

main.html view:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form ng-submit='addThing()'>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <input type="text" ng-model="newThing">
      <input type="submit" value="Add Thing">
    </div>
  </form>
  <li ng-repeat='thing in awesomeThings'>
    {{thing}}
  </li>
  <h4>Awesome things: {{awesomeThings}}</h4>
  <h4>Cool things: {{coolThings}}</h4>
</div>
```

When I look at the inspector in the Network tab for the "/users" route, it loads users.html.  This doesn't happen for the "/" route.  I expect it to load main.html, but I get nothing.

The strange thing is, when I copy all of my code from my main.js and just throw it into my users.js, everything works fine.  This told me maybe I wasn't loading it properly into the index.html page, but it seems to me that I am.

index.html:
(scripts are at the bottom)

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-app="rantlyApp">

    <header class='nav-header' role='navigation'>
      <div class='content'>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">Rantly</a>
        <nav>
          <a href="#/">Rants</a>
          <a href="#/users">Users</a>
          <a href="#/styleguide">Styleguide</a>
          <a href="#/signup">Sign Up</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
      <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
    <script>
    !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
      (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
      r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
    }(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/users.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm extremely new to Angular so it's quite possible I'm missing a fundamental step in setting up the controllers.  Since my code works based purely off of which file I have it in, I have a feeling I'm not configuring something properly in Angular.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
var rantlyApp = angular.module('rantlyApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

You are creating a new module called `rantlyApp` and removing any old module with the same name. So when the `users.js` script runs it overwrites what you defined in `main.js`.
Instead define your module once, and retrieve it with:

```
var rantlyApp = angular.module('rantlyApp');
```

Check the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module).

Comment: Ah, yes.  It hadn't occurred to me that I was creating new modules with new dependencies each time in my controllers.  I had the angular module defined in my app.js initially with a long list of dependencies, and thought I was referencing that each time in each of my controllers.

Thanks!